# Passing dynamic input and updating visual in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

The script below when executed creates a process_map() with a select input. Upon selecting a resource like "r1","r2" etc. we get the corresponding process map. However I want to dynamically pass an input from the selectInput bar and update the process map within R shiny page [Snapshot for your reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCZdO.png). Please help.

```
## app.R ##
install.packages("bupaR")
install.packages("edeaR")
install.packages("eventdataR")
install.packages("processmapR")
install.packages("processmonitR")
install.packages("xesreadR")
install.packages("petrinetR")
install.packages("shiny")
install.packages("shinydashboard")
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(bupaR)
library(edeaR)
library(eventdataR)
library(processmapR)
library(processmonitR)
library(xesreadR)
library(petrinetR)
ui <- dashboardPage(
dashboardHeader(),
dashboardSidebar(

selectInput("resources","Select the resource", c("r1","r2","r3","r4","r5"), 
selected = "r1",selectize = T)
),
dashboardBody(
filter_resource(patients,resources = c("r1","r2","r4"), reverse = F) %>% 
process_map()
))
server <- function(input, output) { 
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You should provide minimal reproducible example for the community to help you out

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for replying, it's a complete code with a very minimal example, most of the script contains installing and loading some packages, please run the code and see for yourself, I just need the dynamic functionality added to the map.

Comment: @Patrik_P, kindly help as I am unable to proceed furthur.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(bupaR)
library(edeaR)
library(eventdataR)
library(processmapR)
library(processmonitR)
library(xesreadR)
library(petrinetR)
ui <- dashboardPage(
dashboardHeader(),
dashboardSidebar(

selectInput("resources","Select the resource", c("r1","r2","r3","r4","r5"),selected = "r1",selectize = T)
),
dashboardBody(
  uiOutput("ui")
))
server <- function(input, output) { 
  output$ui <- renderUI({
    r <- input$resources
    tagList(filter_resource(patients,resources = r, reverse = F) %>% process_map())
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Spellbound Sir, very big big help, may god bless you 1000 years of age. thank you so much.

Comment: Hi LukeA, I tried to replicate slider functionality instead of selectInput in your code above, I have written new piece of code below your code. Please see my code and suggest.

Comment: Hi LukeA, regarding this help you provided me earlier, with the above post, I have a certain query, where I guess you can help:                                            link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46361495/implementing-span-to-click-on-plot-and-move-in-r-shiny

Comment: tagList is the magic here , i was trying to renderUI but wasnot helping upvoted

Comment: Hi @lukeA , i have a user click data to visulize but there are too many steps so UIoutput is very small, is there there a way we can handle scale the size of the map.