# Aligning plots to the center of the box() in R shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

the script below creates two plots within two boxes in R shiny dashboard page which are aligned to the right of the box, I wish to align these plots  center of the box.These packages are the minimum required packages to create the given plots. Please help.

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(bupaR)
library(edeaR)
library(eventdataR)
library(processmapR)
library(processmonitR)
library(xesreadR)
library(petrinetR)

ui <- dashboardPage(
dashboardHeader(
),
dashboardSidebar(
width = 0
),
dashboardBody(
box(title = "Process Map", status = "primary",height = "575", solidHeader = 
T,patients %>% process_map(),align = "left"),
box(title = "Resource Map", status = "primary",height = "575", solidHeader = 
T,
resource_map(patients, render = T))
)
)

server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying, I tried that but won't work, align seems to be a css attribute and cannot be used in this context.

Comment: I would greatly appreciate if you can help me as I am stuck at this problem for a while now.

Comment: As the plot lies within the box, fluidrow()  also does not work. Tried it inside and outside the box both, If you can position any of your plots that way, please share the piece of script.

Comment: It's a stubborn plot, won't move :), tried that too. Actually, it's a process map, not a figure created using plot(), maybe we need something different here.

Comment: don't know if this was mentioned already, but what if you first just make changes in the css styles until you have a nicely centered plot and then transfer the changes you made into the R code with a `head` and a `style` tag

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the htmlwidgets are initialized with 960 pixels width or so. Two ways to override this could be:

```
pmap <- patients %>% process_map()
pmap$width <- "100%"
rmap <- resource_map(patients, render = T)
rmap$width <- "100%"
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    width = 0
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    box(
      title = "Process Map", 
      status = "primary",height = "575", 
      solidHeader = T,
      pmap,
      align = "left"),
    box(
      title = "Resource Map", 
      status = "primary",
      height = "575", 
      solidHeader = T, 
      rmap
    )
  )
)
```

or

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    width = 0
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tags$head(tags$style(HTML(".grViz { width:100%!important;}"))),  
    box(
      title = "Process Map", 
      status = "primary",height = "575", 
      solidHeader = T,
      patients %>% process_map(),
      align = "left"),
    box(
      title = "Resource Map", 
      status = "primary",
      height = "575", 
      solidHeader = T, 
      resource_map(patients, render = T)
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: Sir, I wish we had a way to salute the developer on this site, perfectly what I was looking for, didn't know about the html widgets information, very helpful.

Comment: I am also struggling very hard with one more issue, would appreciate your help on this.                                                                                                
link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46128437/passing-dynamic-input-and-updating-visual-in-r-shiny?noredirect=1#comment79220189_46128437

Comment: @AshminKaul See my answer there.